# {!! Form::model not working in laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5.1

I'm trying to fill my form when user Clicks Edit
Thing is my form is not filled.
I've checked that the $tournament variable passed to the view contains right information.
I could just set default value to $tournament->field, but I saw in [laracast](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/13) that it is not necesary, there is a simpler way to do it.

Here is my controller
    class TournamentController extends Controller
    {

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $places = Place::lists('name', 'id');
    $tournament = Tournament::findOrFail($id);
    return view('tournaments.edit', compact('tournament', 'places'));
}
```

Model

```
class Tournament extends Model {

protected $table = 'Tournament';
public $timestamps = true;

protected $fillable = [
    'name',
    'tournamentDate',
    'registerDateLimit',
    'placeId'

];

protected $dates = ['tournamentDate','registerDateLimit'];

public function geTournamentDateAttribute($date)
{
    return $date == "0000-00-00 00:00:00" ? "0000-00-00 00:00:00" : $date;
}

public function getLimitRegisterDateAttribute($date)
{
    return $date == "0000-00-00 00:00:00" ? "0000-00-00 00:00:00" : $date;
}
public function setTournamentDateAttribute($date){
    $this->attributes['tournamentDate'] = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $date);
}
public function setLimitRegisterDateAttribute($date){
    $this->attributes['registerDateLimit'] = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $date);
}

}
```

View

edit.blade.php

```
@extends('app')

@section('content')

<h1>@lang('crud.editModel', ['currentModelName' => $currentModelName])</h1>
<hr/>
{!! Form::model($tournament, ['method'=>"PATCH", "action" => ["TournamentController@update", $tournament->id]]) !!}

@include("tournaments.form", ["submitButton" => "@lang('crud.updateModel', ['currentModelName' => $currentModelName])"])


{!! Form::close()!!}

@include("errors.list")
@stop
```

form.blade.php

```
<div class="form-group">
{!!  Form::label('name', trans('crud.name')) !!}
{!!  Form::text('name', '', ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
</div>

<div class="form-group">
{!!  Form::label('tournamentDate', trans('crud.eventDate')) !!}
{!!  Form::input('date', 'tournamentDate', \Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d'), ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
</div>

<div class="form-group">
{!!  Form::label('limitRegistrationDate', trans('crud.fullLimitDateRegistration')) !!}
{!!  Form::input('date', 'limitRegistrationDate', \Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d'), ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
{!!  Form::label('placeId', trans('crud.place')) !!}
{!!  Form::select('placeId', $places,null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
{!!  Form::submit($submitButton, ['class' => 'btn btn-primary form-control']) !!}
</div>
```

Any idea???

Answer (score 0):

I think according to the Laravel Collective docs on [Form Model Binding](http://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.1/html#form-model-binding), you need to supply a resource route ( rather than an action )

```
echo Form::model($user, array('route' => array('user.update', $user->id)))
```

Comment: what about

 Form::date('name', \Carbon\Carbon::now());

rather that Form::input('date',etc etc

Comment: ErrorException in Macroable.php line 81: Method date does not exist.

Comment: Ok so what version of Laravel Collective Forms and HTML?

http://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.1/html

Comment: "illuminate/html": "^5.0",

Comment: Maybe jump to 5.1.* ?

Comment: - The requested package illuminate/html could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
-->https://packagist.org/packages/illuminate/html

Comment: HTML library is maintained by laravel anymore

See

http://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.1/html

Answer (score 0):

Try this on your edit method:

```
return view('tournaments.edit', ['tournament'=>$this->tournament, 'places'=>$places ]);
```

or

```
return view('tournaments.edit', compact('tournament'), compact('places'));
```